# "SMTP protocol error" when sending mail in emacs

Tags: email, emacs, smtp

I'm trying to configure emacs to send mail through an SMTP server, but so far, I've not been successful. Here's the output I'm getting:

```
220 __SMTP.SERVER__ ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4+UW11.03/8.14.4+UW13.09; Wed, 15 Jan 2014 13:16:39 -0800
250-__SMTP.SERVER__ Hello __LOCAL.DOMAIN__ [__IP.ADDRESS__], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 60000000
250-DSN
250-AUTH GSSAPI
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
250 2.1.0 <__USER@DOMAIN__>... Sender ok
530 5.7.1 Relaying denied. Proper authentication required.
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed; SMTP protocol error
```

Relevant **init.el** is setup thus:

```
(setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it)
(setq smtpmail-smtp-server "__SMTP.SERVER__")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl)
(setq smtpmail-debug-info t)
(setq smtpmail-debug-verb t)
```

There also exists a **.authinfo** file, which reads:

```
machine __SMTP.SERVER__ port 587 login __USER__ password *
```

Any thoughts on what I've missed or done incorrectly?

---

EDIT 1

@techie007 I've talked with the server admin, and he's told me that the server is supposed to allow relaying after authentication; now I'm wondering if I've set up my authentication incorrectly. I know that the server uses TLS encryption, and I know that I've configured `smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl` instead of `'tls`, but the emacs documentation led me to believe that `'ssl` is to be used for both SSL and TLS connections (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/smtpmail.html#Encryption). Is this wrong?

Additionally, the SMTP server does indeed work with other clients; it's just this particular connection that I'm having trouble making.

---

EDIT 2

A retooling of **init.el** now reads:

```
 (setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("__SMPT.SERVER__" 587 nil nil))
      smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("__SMTP.SERVER" 587 "__USER__" nil))
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "__SMTP_SERVER__"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "__SMTP.SERVER__"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      smtpmail-local-domain "__LOCAL.DOMAIN__")
```

which has removed the need for a **.authinfo** file. Full log including an attempt to send mail:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50psvn.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs23/site-start.d/50vm-init.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
goto-history-element: Beginning of history; no preceding item
Quit
Loading /home/__USER__/.xemacs/init.el (source)...done
Loading /home/__USER__/.xemacs/custom.el (source)...done
/usr/bin/mail is not an executable. Setting mail-interactive to t.
Adding vm-rfaddons-option `check-recipients'.
Adding vm-rfaddons-option `check-for-empty-subject'.
Adding vm-rfaddons-option `encode-headers'.
VM-RFADDONS: VM is now infected.
ispell.el is already loaded
Sending...
Added to /home/__USER__/vm-folders/SentMail
sendmail-send-it: Sending...failed with exit value 1
```

---

EDIT 3

I've managed to make some progress! On initial startup of Emacs, I start VM with `C-x m`, and if I try to send a message, I'm met with the failure in the first output - `smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed; SMTP protocol error`. However, if I `C-x C-f ~/.emacs` to open the file and then enter `M-x eval-buffer`, I can then go back into VM and send a message perfectly fine. The **.emacs** configuration is thus:

```
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "__SMTP.SERVER__"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "__SMTP.SERVER__"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl
      smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("__SMTP.SERVER__" 587 "__USER__" "__PASSWORD__"))
)
```

Does anybody know how I can eliminate the need to evaluate `.emacs` at the start of every Emacs session?

---

FINAL EDIT

It works! For closure's sake, let me post my final working configuration here.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/vm/")
(require 'vm-autoloads)
(load "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/vm/vm-reply")
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      user-mail-address "__USER.MAIL.ADDRESS__"
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "__SMTP.SERVER__" 
      smtpmail-smtp-server "__SMTP.SERVER__"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl
      smtpmail-smtp-user "__USER__"
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("__SMTP.SERVER__" 587 "__USER__" nil)))
      starttls-use-gnutls t 
      starttls-gnutls-program "gnutls-cli"
      starttls-extra-arguments nil
)
```

Putting in the `'load-path` and `'vm-autoloads` seemed to help with a couple of "function definition is void" errors, and the manual load of `vm-reply` is a workaround to a bug found in VM 8.2.0b, consisting of a missing autoload; otherwise, it resulted in a void definition of `vm-select-recipient-from-sender`. I also went back to using the .authinfo file to authenticate once I realized that it was conflicting with the `smtpmail-auth-credentials` variable; `smtpmail-smtp-user` is used in conjunction with .authinfo as per **netawater**'s suggestion. `user-mail-address` solved any remaining authentication errors I had.

Thanks, everyone, for all your help and suggestions!

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to Relay through a mail server that disallows Relaying. "5.7.1 Relaying denied."  Just being authenticated may not be enough, depending on how the server is set up.  Have you spoken to the mail server admins yet regarding their chosen rules? Can you send mail from this computer/network using that account and mail server via a standard mail client?

Comment: The log shows you never authenticated. The question is ... why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `smtpmail-smtp-user`, `smtpmail` needs it to look up credentials in the `authinfo` file.

Comment: This was the final little push I needed to fix the authentication issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Two things are strange about the SMTP output at the top of the question:

```
250-STARTTLS
```

The server proposes `STARTTLS`, even though you've set `smtpmail-stream-type` to `ssl` and therefore should have an encrypted connection already.  I'm not sure how to check whether this is the case, and if not, how to fix this.

There is some terminology confusion here: SSL and TLS are *actually* basically the same thing.  SSL version 3.0 and TLS version 1.0 are very similar protocols, and you rarely need to care about the difference.  STARTTLS is a way of setting up an encrypted connection: instead of the connection being encrypted from the start, the connection starts out unencrypted, the server offers encryption, the client accepts it, and then they negotiate an encrypted connection.  However, for some reason almost all mail clients use "SSL" to refer to non-STARTTLS encrypted connections (SSL or TLS), and "TLS" to refer to STARTTLS-encrypted connections.  Emacs does not, so it might be worth trying setting `smtpmail-stream-type` to `starttls`.

```
250-AUTH GSSAPI
```

The server proposes `GSSAPI` as the only authentication method, but `smtpmail` only supports `PLAIN`, `LOGIN` and `CRAM-MD5`.  Unless the server would propose other authentication methods on encrypted connections, it seems like you're out of luck trying to send email from Emacs through this server.

Comment: Doesn't exactly solve my problem, but it does clear several things up and increase my comprehension. While the server does indeed try to impose GSSAPI, a conversation with the sysadmin revealed that the server also supports PLAIN. I did still need to use STARTTLS in some fashion, anyway. Thanks!